# reset jquery variable to initial

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm creating a ajax post load for my wordpress project.

When I scroll down to page, page number increased by 1 each time. which is initially I want.

Actual problem:

When I select a category drop down, I want to reset page variable to 1.
Following code set the page number to 1 for the instance it is called, and then when I scroll down to page it increased with the previous number not with 1.

For Ex:
When I open this link and inspect in firebug...

```
- I see pageNumber variable set to 1.
- Now scroll down to page and it will be changed 2. Now when I go back to up and select any category to filter posts, and 
- Inspect page number in firebug it is now showing 1, which is right. 
- But Now if you scroll down to page you will pagenumber is changed to    3 not 2.
```

This is the problem...

```
// ajaxLoop.js
jQuery(function($){
var $grid = $('.post-area').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.post-area .box',
    });
var page = 1; // initialization
var loading = true;
var $window = $(window);
var $content = $("body.blog #main");
var load_posts = function( page = 1, cat = '', year = '', orderby = '' ){
        // If any filter is applied and page is 1
        if((cat != '' || year != '' || orderby != '') &&  page == 1){
            $content.html('');
            page = 1; // I think this will reset the page variable to 1, but it is not working
        }
        $.ajax({
            type       : "GET",
            data       : {numPosts : 1, pageNumber: page, cat: cat, year: year, orderby: orderby},
            dataType   : "html",
            url        : "wp-content/themes/theme-name/loopHandler.php",
            beforeSend : function(){
                if(page != 1){
                    $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">\
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/ajax-loader.gif" />\
                        </div>');
                }
            },
            success    : function(data){

                $data = $(data);
                if($data.length){
                    $data.hide();
                    $content.append($data);
                    $grid.append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data );
                    $grid.masonry( 'reloadItems' );
                    $grid.masonry( 'layout' ); 
                    $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                        $("#temp_load").remove();
                        loading = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#temp_load").remove();
                }
            },
            error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#temp_load").remove();
                alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }
    });
}
$window.scroll(function() {
    var content_offset = $content.offset();
    console.log(content_offset.top);
    if(!loading && ($window.scrollTop() +
        $window.height()) > ($content.scrollTop() + $content.height() + content_offset.top)) {
            loading = true;
            var cat = $('select[name="cat"]').val();
            var year = $('select[name="year"]').val();
            var orderby = $('select[name="orderby"]').val();
            page++;
            load_posts( page, cat, year, orderby);
    }
});
$('select[name="cat"]').on('change', function() {
    var cat = $(this).val();
    var year = $('select[name="year"]').val();
    var orderby = $('select[name="orderby"]').val();
    load_posts(1, cat, year, orderby);
});

$('select[name="year"]').on('change', function() {
    var year = $(this).val();
    var cat = $('select[name="cat"]').val();
    var orderby = $('select[name="orderby"]').val();
    load_posts(1, cat, year, orderby);
});

$('select[name="orderby"]').on('change', function() {
    var orderby = $(this).val();
    var cat = $('select[name="cat"]').val();
    var year = $('select[name="year"]').val();
    load_posts(1, cat, year, orderby);
});

load_posts();
});
```

I think there must be a easy solution to this, but not to figure it out.
Can anybody guide me in the right direction? I'm not so ninja with jquery...

Comment: If it's something you click on, why not just check for a click on that specific type of element, and then set the value to 1?

Comment: this is because of scope of your variable `page`. If the same variable is available in both of the methods scope, it will not create this problem..

Comment: `if((cat != '' || year != '' || orderby != '') &&  page == 1){` what is the requirement of setting `page = 1`  if its already `1`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Yes, I agree, it is due to scope of the variable. But what should I make so that it can work? Can you please guide? Thanks for the comment...

Comment: the condition i have specified above in my comment is forcing page variable to reset to 1 if its 1..that's why its not working

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Noh, Initially there is no filter applied to page. So it will load all the posts.
Now when filter is applied, I checked with this condition that : If filter is applied and page count to one, remove content from DIV. If ill remove that page == 1, and scroll down to page with every page count update it will clear content of my DIV.

Comment: then make it `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Whatever you want to do with that condition i am not disagree on that part. But just tell me one thing..if condition say `page == 1` then reset `page = 1`. What does that mean?

Comment: Oh coz I thought Doing this will set the gloabal value of variable page to 1, so that when It is increased by the another function it increase to two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you,

remove `page` parameter from `load_posts`

And in case of your `change` event before calling `load_posts` function set this `page` value to 1

Comment: Thanks a lot man, That worked. Have been working on it from last couple of hour but wasn't able to figure out this. Thanks again.

Comment: as @ PardeepDhingra told it was the scope issue. When you try to set page to 1 in load_posts it sets this value to you local page variable of your load_posts function and not to the global one so, was the issue.

Comment: Yes, I was sure it is something related to scope of variable but was not able to solve it. Thank for the description. :)